# PHP's SimpleXML ignoring the XML (kinda)

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have a very short (so far), very basic XML file called config.xml like

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<name_of_program3>
    <path_to_exe3>script.pl</path_to_exe3>
    <path_to_perl>/usr/bin/perl</path_to_perl>
    <temp_output_file>temp.txt</temp_output_file>
</name_of_program3>
```

I am trying to read it with the following PHP:

```
$config = simplexml_load_file('config.xml');

$exe = $config->name_of_program3->path_to_exe3;
$perl_exec = $config->name_of_program3->path_to_perl;
$temp_file = $config->name_of_program3->temp_output_file;
```

None of the XML elements are read; `$exe`, `$perl_exec`, and `$temp_file` are all empty, but printing `$config` with `$config->asXML()` reveals that the XML is, in fact, there.

Please tell me I am doing something silly so that I can stop banging my head against my desk. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root node shouldn't be used (all xml documents must have a root node, so it's presence is assumed/required), try:

```
$config->path_to_perl
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should read without name_of_program3 because the one is root.
Try to use

$exe = $config->path_to_exe3